# Cannot pass variable with apostrophe in "a href" link

Tags: php

I select a list of names from mysqli database then display row details in display.php with if (isset($_GET['name']));
The link is

```
$str = strtoupper($str);
echo "<tr><td><a href='php/display.php?name=$str'>$str</a></td></tr>";
```

This executes correctly unless name contains '(apostrophe).

For instance `$str` (as input/click) shows as `L'ECLIPSE` but the `<a>` link only `L'`
The result in display.php is 'No data found for your request'

I have found exact same queries on this site but none of the answers have resolved my problem. Perhaps I am not implementing correctly.
I assume this is about escaping. But I know little about it.

Comment: The apostrophe is breaking the link because the href is surrounded with single quotes. You'll need to encode it or add slashes

Comment: I tried slashes and addslashes() but only found urlencode() (another answer here) to work for my code.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

$str = strtoupper($str);
echo "<tr><td><a href='php/display.php?name=".urlencode($str)."'>$str</a></td></tr>";
```

[urlencode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) the string first. So you don't get this kind of problems.

Comment: Using urlencode() I get exactly what I want from my code. Thanks.

Answer (score -3):

Try this code.

```
    <?php
    $str = strtoupper($str);
    echo "<tr><td><a href='php/display.php? 
    name=".htmlspecialchars($str)."'>$str</a></td></tr>";
    ?>
```

Your Single quote    becomes &#039 ; 
I hope it will help

Comment: This doesn't work, try `$str = "Apos' heal";` for example. htmlspecialchars does not convert `'` single quote without mention the `ENT_QUOTES` flag.