# how can I pass dynamically an href attiribute containing an apostrophe to an anchor tag in a php script?

Tags: php, html, string, href

I have a MySQL table containing filenames and a query dependent on some user choice returning these filenames in a PHP script, say in a variable $filename. I want to create anchor  tags with the `href` attribute pointing to these filenames so that the user can download the relevant PDF files stored in directory.
I tried to code like this:

```
echo "<a href='".$filename."' target='_blank'> my pdf file</a>";
```

but if the filename contains an apostrophe (') the link appears broken in the browser.
I have also tried escaping the apostrophe in the filename with backslash with no luck.
Additionally I tried delimiting the string containing the anchor tag inside single quotes, but this doesn't allow inline code like `$filename`.
Then I saw this SO question [Cannot pass variable with apostrophe in "a href" link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58399474/cannot-pass-variable-with-apostrophe-in-a-href-link), but it doesn't seem to work.
Would constructing the href attribute in client-side javascript be of any help?

Comment: "but it doesn't seem to work" post what you tried, because it should work.

Comment: @Sammitch Ok I dit it! I hijacked the sql query return thing and hardcoded the result in variable $url as follows: $url="uploads/94/04/".urlencode("52909-05_You_Don't _Know_JS_Async_&_Performance.pdf"); and then echo "<br><a href='$url'>my pdf file</a>"; the link almost works but fails. Now I see that the suspicious filename contains a blank after "You_Don't " (not evident is this comment) which ruins the whole thing. In the browser it shows a '+' representing this blank. But is if I use rawurlencode then it works

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```php
echo '<a href="' . $filename . '" target="_blank">my pdf file</a>';
```

Or:

```php
echo "<a href='$filename' target='_blank'>my pdf file</a>";
```

Or with `urlencode` (the most reliable):

```php
echo '<a href="' . urlencode( $filename ) . '" target="_blank">my pdf file</a>';
```

Answer (score -1):

What if you invert the quotes and apostrophes like this:

```
echo '<a href="'.$filename.'" target="_blank"> my pdf file</a>';
```